# MySQL BETWEEN and ">= AND <=" giving different results

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any difference between MySQL BETWEEN operator and using ">= <="?

When i tried them on this query, they give different results.

```
SELECT 
      tblStaff.TitleGredCd,
      count(StudCourse1.StaffNoIC),     
      StudCourse1.StaffNoIC,
      StaffNm,
      BranchNm, 
      StDt, 
      EndDt, 
      SUM(datediff(EndDt,StDt)+1)  
      TotalDay, 
      (SELECT SUM( pembelajaranhour ) 
         FROM tblpembelajaran d 
         WHERE d.StaffNoIC = tblStaff.StaffNoIC
           AND YEAR( PembelajaranDate ) = 2011 )Totalhour,
      (SELECT SUM( datediff( kendiridate, kendiridate ) +1 ) 
         FROM tblkendiri d 
         WHERE d.StaffNoIC = tblStaff.StaffNoIC 
           AND YEAR( kendiridate ) = 2011 ) Totalkendiriday
   FROM 
      StudCourse1, 
      tblStaff 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN tblRefBranch 
            ON tblStaff.BranchCd = tblRefBranch.BranchCd, 
      tblRefTitleGred
   WHERE 
          StudCourse1.StaffNoIC = tblStaff.StaffNoIC 
      AND tblStaff.TitleGredCd = tblRefTitleGred.TitleGredCd 
     [Date Condition]
   GROUP BY 
      tblStaff.TitleGredCd, 
      StudCourse1.StaffNoIC
```

If I use `AND StDt BETWEEN '2011-1-1' AND '2011-12-31'` for `[Date Condition]` I get 6 returned results.
But if I use `AND StDt >= '2011-1-1' AND EndDt '2011-12-31'` for `[Date Condition]` I get 7 returned results.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post both WHERE clauses exactly as you've run them, please? (You say `AND StDt >= '2011-1-1' AND EndDt '2011-12-31'`; I guess you're missing an operator there. Seeing both clauses exactly would help us to figure out what's going on.) It would also be helpful to know the value of StDt for the row that's different between your two result sets, assuming there is one row different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BETWEEN is a bit odd with DATE types.  What you are saying with your date types is

```
// These 2 are the same
BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 00:00:00'
```

and so it only match up to '2011-12-30 23:59:59', or to put it another way on a DATE field it won't match '2011-12-30'.

When you search for '2011-01-01' <= .... <= '2011-12-31' it then correctly matches the date being potentially == '2011-12-31'

So you have 4 options.  The first one is to add 1 day onto the upper bound.  **This is the option I usually utilise**  The BETWEEN plays very nicely with an index on the date column, and there's no CAST or DATE() used on the data rows as the `ADDDATE('2011-12-31',1)` only needs executing once

```
WHERE `StDt` BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND ADDDATE('2011-12-31',1)
```

The second is to explicitly specify the timestamp

```
WHERE `StDt`BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 23:59:59'
```

The third, as you've found, is to use <= and >=

```
WHERE `StDt` >= '2011-01-01' AND `StDt` <= '2011-12-31'
```

A fourth option that also seems to work is the following, but I still prefer the first method as it's the one I know works + doesn't require using CAST or DATE on every row

```
WHERE DATE(`StDt`) BETWEEN DATE('2011-01-01') AND DATE('2011-12-31')
```

I hope this is of help

Comment: @Jamie, yup on the dates... I would actually take the END date and add 1 day to it and ensure LESS than, so the entire previous day would be completely included... < 2012-01-01  (which is same as 2011-12-31 23:59:59) as noted by Simon

Answer (score 1):

```
AND StDt BETWEEN '2011-1-1' AND '2011-12-31'
```

Checks whether the value in the column `StDt` is between the two values.

```
AND StDt >= '2011-1-1' AND EndDt <= '2011-12-31'
```

Checks whether the value in `StDt` is GTE a value, and the value is `EndDt` is LTE a value.

The first uses the value of only one column, the second uses the values of two. So they will return different results, they are different conditions. The only way they would be the same is if the value of `StDt` was always equal to the value of `EndDt` for every row.

To mimic the behaviour of your first `BETWEEN` clause with GTE/LTE operators, you would do this:

```
AND StDt >= '2011-1-1' AND StDt <= '2011-12-31'
```

This should return the same set of results.

Answer (score 0):

You can see more explain on reference on mysql

> For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type. Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to two DATE values, convert the DATE values to DATETIME values. If you use a string constant such as '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a DATE, cast the string to a DATE.

I suggest you continue use <= and >= for more exact results